# Knife upload data bag fails with Chef::ChefFS::FileSystem::OperationNotAllowedError

Tags: chef, knife

I am currently doing the Chef tutorials provided at learn.chef.io. In the fourth workshop, one of the steps is to create some data bags and then upload them using:

```
knife upload data-bags/vhosts
```

The actual data bag objects are in .json files within the vhosts directory.

When I execute that command, the error that I get is:

```
ERROR: Chef::ChefFS::FileSystem::OperationNotAllowedError: Chef::ChefFS::FileSystem::OperationNotAllowedError
```

It isn't an ownership problem of the files or filesystem, I ran as root as well just in case, and get the same error.

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide the output of the same upload command with `-VV` for verbose output?